# Ruta anidada dinámica en vue/nuxt - No encuentra el path "/static/images"

Tags: vue.js, router, nuxt

Tengo una aplicacion en vue que tiene un header general para todo el sitio. En él se cargan imágenes que tengo en la carpeta `static/images` en la raiz de mi proyecto. Sencillamente coloco las imágenes así y las encuentra bien:

```
      <img
        src="/images/logo-desktop.png" // tambien puedo poner src="images/logo-desktop.png"
        alt=""
        width="100%"
        style="border-radius: 50%"
      />
```

Ahora, si yo accedo a cualquier parte de mi proyecto, como el header no vuelve a cargarse, se ve todo perfecto.

El problema ocurre cuando yo accedo directamente a una ruta dinamica, como `localhost:3000/noticias/13` sin haber pasado por el inicio antes, o por alguna ruta de tipo `localhost:3000/path`, es decir el problema ocurre cuando hay dos niveles de rutas en la url, en este caso `/noticias/13`

El header no se cargar y recibo por consola muchos errores, que no encuentra ninguna imágen porque las está buscando en `localhost:3000/noticias/images/logo-desktop.png`

> Cómo puedo hacer para omitir en este caso `/noticias/` de la URL que se genera para buscar la imágen? yo necesito que vaya a buscarla a `localhost:3000/images/logo-desktop.png`

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo, necesitaba obtener la URL BASE, en este caso `http://localhost:3000/`. Para ello agregué en el archivo `nuxt.config.js`

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },
```

Ahora puedo acceder a la URL BASE de mi sitio desde `this.$config.BASE_URL`. Finalmente a todas las imágenes las llamo de la siguiente forma

```
   <img :src="`${this.$config.BASE_URL}images/my-image.png`" />
```